# How to instantiate JavaScript object with only properties passed in?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to have a object that takes in fields like this:

```
var User = function(params) {
    if(params){
        this.id = params.id;
        this.name = params.name;
        ..
    }
}
```

- if a property of a field in the model, it sets them
- if it does not match the model it does not get included in the model
- if the property is not there it does not set it

So if you do this:

```
var data = {
    id: 123,
    foo: 'bar'
};

var user = new User(data);

JSON.stringify(user); // { id: 123 }
```

What's the easiest way to do this? I can only think to do a conditional for each property.

Comment: What's wrong with your attempt? Seems fine to me.

Comment: use an extend() function

Comment: @falsarella the issue was the undefined property. Answer is below to return a parsed stringified version of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sincerely, you don't need conditionals. Your attempt is perfectly fine. Just execute the following code:

```
function User(params, hiddenNew) {
    if (params) {
        //if a property of a field in the model, it sets them
        //if it does not match the model it does not get included in the model
        this.id = params.id;
        this.name = params.name;
    }
    //you can have additional functions here, or add it to its prototype
    this.logMe = function() {
        console.log(this);
    };
    //if the property is not there it does not set it
    for (key in this) {
        if (this[key] == undefined) {
            delete this[key];
        }
    }
    return this;
}
var data = {
    id: 123,
    foo: 'bar'
};

var user = new User(data);
user.logMe(); // testing function
```

And the `user` object will be exactly what you want:

> `User {id: 123}`

Comment: Why the downvote? Can the downvoter explain the reason?

Comment: +1 from me. With the behavior of `undefined` being as it is, this passes the few conditions the OP gave. There's still a difference in the object which may or may not play any role, but largely it's irrelevant whether the property is actually undefined or just `undefined`.

Comment: This is actually the best way to do it. One tweak is to do `return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this));` in the model. This strips out the undefined automatically. Thanks!

Comment: @deceze I don't want the undefined because I am using it to automatically build a query, and so the query would fail.

Comment: Turns out this is not as good as I thought, it strips the methods out so I can no longer use User to run its methods after I instantiate it. Going to have to figure out a new pattern. ended up just adding a new method `User.prototype.model = function(data){ return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new User(data))); };` seems silly, but works.

Comment: @PixMach Good point. I've rewritten the logic to suppress the usage of `JSON.parse/JSON.stringify` - it really seemed little hackish and intrusive. See my updated answer. I think it's much better now, and fits to your new requirement of not shadowing an internal function.

Answer (score 2):

```
function (params) {
    var properties = ['id', 'name', ..];
    for (var i = 0, length = properties.length; i < length; i++) {
        var property = properties[i];
        if (params[property]) {
            this[property] = params[property];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no other way than conditionally-adding them, but you can simplify it.

Since JavaScript is a dynamically-typed language and it also enforces duck-typing, don't expect something like *classes* that could auto-magically prevent adding unexpected properties.

See the following code snippet for a possible simplification.

```js
function BaseObject() {}

BaseObject.prototype = {
  defineRequiredProperties: function(requiredProperties, propertyMap) {
    if (!(requiredProperties instanceof Array)) {
      throw Error("'requiredProperties` argument must be an array!");
    }

    if (typeof propertyMap == "object") {
      var that = this;

      Object.keys(propertyMap).forEach(function(propertyName) {
        // Better do this because you'll be able to check if a 
        // property exists even if it's defined in the prototype chain
        if (requiredProperties.indexOf(propertyName) > -1) {
          that[propertyName] = propertyMap[propertyName];
        }
      });
    }
  }
};

// As OP requested, this prevents this custom function from being iterated.
// It's still callable but not enumerable
Object.defineProperty(BaseObject.prototype, "defineRequiredProperties", {
    enumerable: false
});

function User(params) {
  this.defineRequiredProperties(["id", "name"], params);
}

// This is effecitvely derive BaseObject (actually, chaining the
// BaseObject prototype) in order to share defineRequiredProperties
// across all your custom prototypes and be DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)
User.prototype = Object.create(BaseObject.prototype);

var user = new User({
  id: 11,
  name: "Matías",
  lastName: "Fidemraizer"
});

document.getElementById("result").textContent = JSON.stringify(user);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't pass the requirement "*if the property is not there it does not set it*" -- it sets it to `null` (e.g., remove `name: "Matías"` and run it)

Comment: What @Tom said. if you have the object look like this: `this.id = null;
    this.name = null;
    this.anotherField = null;` you get `{"id":11,"name":"Matías","anotherField":null}`

Comment: @PixMach Now it passes the requirement ;) I've updated the code

Comment: It actually only does because of the stringify, if you actually print the object you will still have the undefined property (which is still not shown in your snippit). Thanks for the try though!

Comment: @PixMach Sorry? An unexisting property is undefined, obviously

Comment: @PixMach What's *printing* for you?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer the problem is that I'm using that data to automatically update a database, so the tool will parse the object and get to the `otherField: undefined` and break because that field does not exist in the db.

Comment: @PixMach Do you mean something like `console.log(user.whatever)` where `whatever` isn't a property? This will always print `undefined`, **because it's undefined**, and `JSON.stringify` can't include an unexisting property or undefined property, because it's undefined after all :D

Comment: @PixMach Read my last comment. I believe you're wrong, or show me a code snippet where you can prove your statement (for example in jsFiddle.net).

Comment: Yeah but I want the object to be cleaned of that property, so it needs to be parsed after and returned. See the accepted answer for the solution I was looking for. @MatíasFidemraizer

Comment: @PixMach I believe you're wrong. The `User` instance won't contain a property from the `params`!!!!!!!!!!!!! And my approach is more powerful than just relying on dynamic typing, as you define required properties thus there's no way that User will have unwanted properties, either `undefined` or with value

Comment: @PixMach Also, you've accepted an answer which effectively adds undefined properties to `User`. `undefined` is both a possible property value or *unexisting property*. For example, `{ name: undefined }` is possible, which is equivalent to `{ name: params.name }` if params doesn't contain `name`. Try to call `hasOwnProperty` in an user instance where you passed a params with an unwanted property: `user.hasOwnProperty("name")` and it will return `true`, since the property exists with `undefined` value. Be aware about this.

Comment: @PixMach Since JSON.stringify doesn't serialize undefined properties, either if they exist or not, you feel you shouldn't care, but after all, your accepted answer isn't as elegant as you think. This is just my opinion.

Comment: @PixMach I also checked the last edit from accepted answer.... Using serialization to remove undefined properties. Wouldn't it better to just not add undefined properties (like my approach)? Anyway, I'll leave my answer here for other future readers so there's more than a valid approach to the issue

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer your method also has the object have a function in it which will also break my query. I am looking for a clean property list.

Comment: @PixMach It depends on how you iterate properties. If you use `user.HasOwnProperty(propertyName)` when using `for..in` you'll get own object properties only and not ones coming from the prototype chain.

Comment: @PixMach This is why I used `Object.keys`, which gets an array of own property names instead of all properties, including prototype ones

Comment: @PixMach But wait, I can fullfill this requirement too

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I will reference this if I run into issues with the accepted answer.

Comment: @PixMach No problem. BTW my goal isn't getting my answer as the accept one. I participate in SO to provide approaches to the issues. The question's poster decides what's better for himself/herself :)

Answer (score -3):

How about you extend the user properties with passed properties? That way anything new will be added to the user. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Comment: I'm not using jquery, but wouldn't that make the result: `{ id:123, foo: 'bar', name: null }` That's the opposite of what I want.